# Kafka Connect SMT - flattening a message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka message that looks like the below.

```
{
   “prop1”: “val1”,
   “prop2”: “val2”,
   “sub_msg”: {
       “prop3”: “val3”,
       “prop4”: “val4”,
    },
   “prop5”: “val5”
}
```

And I need to flatten it. Like the below.

```
{
   “prop1”: “val1”,
   “prop2”: “val2”,
   “prop3”: “val3”,
   “prop4”: “val4”,
   “prop5”: “val5”
}
```

I am looking at the [ReplaceField](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html) SMT that is able to to replace field names in a flat structure.
My question is - can this SMT handle nested structures as well? Or - is there a "flattener" SMT available out of the box?

**EDIT (1)**

I can see the [flatten](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html) SMT but it adds the "path" of the nested object - If I could disable the "path" concatenation - it could work for me. I cant see anyway to disable it in the docs.

**EDIT (2)**
My current direction is to extend the flattener and make it possible not to concatenate field names.

New configuration fields:

1. *concatenate.field.names* | boolean | default: true
2. *duplicate.field.strategy* |  Enum (FirstSeenWins,LastSeenWins) | default: LastSeenWins

With the two config attributes above one can set the SMT behaviour regarding field names concatenation and control what should happen in case of duplicates

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceField can only be used on top-level fields.

You'd need to combine the flatten transform with the rename transform to be able to remove the `sub_msg` prefixes.

Comment: That is what I thought... Thanks

Comment: Another option would be to extend the flattener and let the user pass a flag that will control the 'path' concatenation. Is that an option?

Comment: You'd need to open a Kafka JIRA ticket and PR for that, but you need to define what happens when you have `{"f1": {"f2": ...}, "f2": ... }`

Comment: Oh.. I have created this https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/issues/34#issue-1195157389. I will be happy to implement this feature.

Comment: Yes. We need to decide which "f2" wins... So two config items should be added. A bool that tells if to concat ( default true ) and a winning strategy.

Comment: I have updated the post with my thoughts about the SMT enhancement - will be glad to get your input.